# is it possible to make a kernel image without using asm code?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel, bios

I've seen many tutorials on the net where `assembly language` is being used along with `C` in order to build a new kernel image. But I don't understand why assembly is that required, while a `C Compiler` can generate `asm` from c code.

What's the reason of using `assembly` code for programming kernels? and how is it possible to develop a kernel under `C` without the need of writing a code in asm?

Comment: I don't think it is what you meant and i didn't know any way to make it work but, you may theoretically force compiler to produce code that you want. Otherwise, i don't think that operating system can support interrupts, task switching and lots of other features.

Comment: I am not sure that [Why assembly needed to kick-start any OS kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794239/why-assembly-needed-to-kick-start-any-os-kernel) is an exact duplicate. That other question focus more on *initializing* and *kick-starting* a kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't define what making a kernel in C means to you.

You could use `asm` statements or declarations to [embed assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) in C code (but that is "cheating" and is no more portable C).

But you cannot write an entire [multi-tasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) kernel in pure portable C, because some things (notably those manipulating tasks or [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) or [call stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) or [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) - i.e. the [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Process_scheduler) - or [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)) cannot be coded in C. Notice that even [longjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) cannot be implemented in pure C.

See the [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/) wiki and read [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

*Study also the source code* of existing schedulers, interrupt handlers, VM subsystems, .... in [*free software*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) operating systems (and ask yourself how would you recode in C the assembler code they are using). Assembler is required in them (and not only or not mostly for "performance" or "readability" reasons).

Comment: I read the VM/sched parts of "Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces" book, but I'm still not getting why asm is required for these cases.

Comment: The kernel is multi-tasking.

Comment: Try to write your scheduler in pure C, you'll fail to do so.

Comment: Ok, understood.